# What is the mechanical Effect of a wall?

Tags: emperor-rise-of-the-middle-kingdom

When Walls are introduced in Emperor: Rise of the Middle Kingdom, they are explained to block the negative effects of low aesthetics on an area on the other side. But how is that actually defined in the game? As an example, swapping a row of gardens for walls, allows the buildings closest to the docks to upgrade:

[image]
[image]